# facebook session not opening

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to add facebook sdk 3.0 for android to my app.

I am trying to login using the function

> OpenSessionWithAllowLoginUI(boolean allowLoginUI)

when state of session changes the function

> SessionStateChanged(session, state, exception)

is called.  These functions are given below.

```
 public void OpenSessionWithAllowLoginUI(boolean allowLoginUI)
    {

    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
           @Override
           public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
           {
               SessionStateChanged(session, state, exception);
           }
    })
}

public void SessionStateChanged(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case OPENED:
              if (exception == null)
              {
                  facebook = new Facebook("6346513133546");
              }

            break;

        case CLOSED:
        case CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED:
            Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            facebook = null;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

On calling the function session state changes twice. First it shows session state as "OPENING" then after logging in and clicking "ok" to the permissions popup, the session state changes to "CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED". The session state is never "OPENED" and i get the following exception

> remote_app_id does not match stored id

Can anyone please tell me what am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that i was not giving the correct key hash. I generated key hash using `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Can you please verify that the app_id on your Android app is exactly the same as the one on your app dashboard (https://developers.facebook.com/apps)?  Also make sure "Native Android App" has a green checkmark, enabled "Facebook Login" and added your key hash.

Comment: I have checked all that. On further checking i found that the exception might be caused coz of giving wrong key hash. I tried adding key hash generated using **keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64** but it dint work